# Undefined is not an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I get the following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.id')

I have this. Get items and delete items:

```
    getItems = async () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true });
    this.unsubscribe = await this.ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const todos = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            todos.push({
              id: doc.id,
              tips: doc.data().tips,
              date: doc.data().date,
              user: doc.data().user,
              like: doc.data().like,
            })
            this.ref.get().then(function(documentSnapshot) {
              // check and do something with the data here.
            });
          })
          this.setState({
            refreshing: false,
            getData: todos
          })
        })
  }
  deletePost({ item, index }){
    var deleteItemId = item.id;
     firestore.collection("tips").doc(deleteItemId).delete().then(function() {
          alert("deleted", deleteItemId)
      }).catch(function(error) {
          alert("Error removing document: ", error);
      });
  }
```

Rendered Items like:

```
renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {

    return (
        <Text onPress={() => this.deletePost(item.id)}>Delete</Text>
    )
 }
```

This is item.id is like `NnX57tSpqvPvIUN7tRY4`

Comment: `sdfsifh` is the string.

Comment: have you checked the type? Seems to be a string

Comment: Hmm, added the error I get. It is undefined

Comment: No, the output is "NnX57tSpqvPvIUN7tRY4" and "iIRTop4TKOBdL5o6dIO3"

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have called the method when there be possible to `undefined`. Make sure `item.id` is not `undefined`:

```
deleteItemId && firestore.collection("tips").doc(deleteItemId).delete()
```